# Why would a content type column not show up in library settings?

Tags: content-type, site-column

**Background**

I have a content type (CT2) with 7 site columns. CT2 inherits from CT1 which has 3 columns.

We are using CT2 in several document libraries.

In one document library

- The columns for CT2 work as expected
- The columns for CT1 display when selecting columns for a view
- The columns for CT1 display in a standard view
- The columns for CT1 **DO NOT** display in a datasheet view
- The columns for CT1 **DO NOT** show up in list settings
- When I attempt to add the site column it does not show up as an option

For the most part it did not seem to make a difference at first but this uncertainty does give me general worry but not being able to do easy edits in datasheet view is an issue now.

**Question**

Is there any reason why a site column from a content type is in a document library would not show up in the document library settings page on in the datasheet view?

Comment: Knowing that "Item" is the parent content type to documents, try to open the item content type in datasheet view, and do you see the columns displayed there?

Comment: How did you create the content type, UI or via Code?

Comment: Have you checked the value of [ShowInListSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showinlistsettings(v=office.15).aspx) for that field?